# Transform TypeScript Interface

Tags: typescript, interface, code-generation

I have a typescript file that contains interfaces like that

```
export interface User { ... }
export interface Product { ... }
export interface Account { ... }

export interface MyType {
  id: number;
  userId: string;
  productId: string;
  accountId: string;
  propX: string;
  propY: number;
}
```

I want to transform interfaces that has prop that ends with `Id` for example `MyType` into that:

```
export interface MyType {
  id: number;
  user: User;
  product: Product;
  account: Account;
  propX: string;
  propY: number;
}
```

or altering interface that way:

```
export interface MyType {
  id: number;
  user: User;
  userId: string;
  product: Product;
  productId: string;
  account: Account;
  accountId: string;
  propX: string;
  propY: number;
}
```

I would like to create a new file one based on the original file that contains interfaces definitions.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wzk5ew) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I want to create a new file, not creating interfaces on the fly. So it will keep the original  interfaces names, etc

Comment: A new file?  So this is code generation then?  Might want to tag it as such because it's not just TypeScript anymore

Comment: @jcalz right, just tagged